# Setting keyboard layout for a particular device using xkbcomp

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm using `xkbcomp` to swap the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> keys on an Apple keyboard of mine.

This works:

```
xkbcomp -w0 -I"$DIR" "$DIR/keymap/mykbd" $DISPLAY
```

...but it changes the layout for all keyboards, and this will not do because I am frequently changing between a standing and sitting position (and swapping keyboards).

I have taken the trouble of specifying a device. The `xkbcomp` help text says: `-i <deviceid>  Specifies device ID (not name) to compile for`

```
xkbcomp -w0 -I"$DIR" -i 16 "$DIR/keymap/mykbd" $DISPLAY
```

...but this seems to produce no effect!

I drew the id `16` from `xinput list | grep Magic\ Keyboard`. I've also tried `/dev/input/event18` as an id, taken from `xinput list-props 16 | grep 'Device Node'`, but this produces no better effect.

**Update:**

Suprisingly, when I provide the id of `Virtual core keyboard` instead of `Magic Keyboard`, I *do* get an effect: the new mapping gets applied to my Magic Keyboard, *and* if I proceed to type on my integrated laptop keyboard, the keymap *then* reverts to the original configuration.

I can't explain this. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: the `id` should be a number like `16` or `18`, not a path like `/dev/input/event18`.  doublecheck with `xinput list` that your hardware isn't presenting two separate entries.  note these device ids aren't guaranteed to remain the same after reboot or unplug/replug.

Comment: @quixotic : thanks for settling that. I did use the id `16` initially. And I have double-checked. (I acknowledge that these ids may change after reboot/unplug.) So the question remains why I get no effect when specifying `-i <id>`

Comment: I ended up customizing my keyboard by use of udev, writing a `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard-local.hwdb` file

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to employ the technique described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69804).

Alternatively, create a separate .xkb file for each device (could use method described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/858272/165265) for each one) and place shortcuts for each on the desktop. Persistence wouldn't be as important since the expectation is that the key layout (device) would be selected manually.